# Javascript - change folder path, not the file

Tags: javascript, replace

Im trying to figure out, on how to replace the folder path and not the img. 
The folder names are always the same, they're are not dynamic. If i click button "one", it should change all my images folder paths to "dist/one/", the same logics goes for the two others.

```
<button id="one" type="button">This should change the path to "dist/one/"</button>
<button id="two" type="button">This should change the path to "dist/two/"</button>
<button id="three" type="button">This should change the path to "dist/three/"</button>

<img src="dist/one/rocket.png" alt="" />
<img src="dist/two/rocket.png" alt="" />
<img src="dist/three/rocket.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: are you trying to replace all images path or just some specific image path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a data attribute for this.  Store a template for the image src and a path value for each button, then update the image src values accordingly for each button click...

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var path = this.getAttribute("data-path");

    [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {

      var src = img.getAttribute("data-src-template").replace("{path}", path);
      img.src = src;
      console.log(img.src);

    });
  });
});

// intialize the image...
document.querySelector("#one").click();
```

```html
<button id="one" type="button" data-path="dist/one">This should change the path to "dist/one/"</button><br/>
<button id="two" type="button" data-path="dist/two">This should change the path to "dist/two/"</button><br/>
<button id="three" type="button" data-path="dist/three">This should change the path to "dist/three/"</button><br/>

<img data-src-template="{path}/rocket.png" alt="" />
<img data-src-template="{path}/rocket.png" alt="" />
<img data-src-template="{path}/rocket.png" alt="" />
```

This gives you what you need as well as being flexible if the path format ever changes, since everything you need is defined in the html and the script never needs to change.

For example, if you decided to move the images into another subfolder you could just change the image tag and it would still work...

```
<img data-src-template="newSubFolder/{path}/rocket.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: I really like your example and the snippet you've shared seems to work, but when I put it all together and simple index.html file, it doesn't work?

i get this console error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at index.html:22

Comment: I'm guessing you've included the script at the top of the page, and the buttons and image are further down the page?

Comment: Yup - that was the problem, than you so much :D

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: One last thing i just noticed - i only works on one image? If i have multiple images, it's doesn't work on the rest :s

Comment: Yes, of course.  I can change it to do more than one image, as per the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166532/discussion-between-giefdonut-and-archer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that by creating script. 
If you assign ID to each of the `<img>` tags you can then do something like:

```
document.getElementById('exampleID').innerHTML="<src="new_path">";
```

Eventually put each `<img>` tag in DIV

```
<div id=someid>
<img src="dist/one/rocket.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML="<img src="new_path"/>";
```

I did not test it but the answer should be really close to this.

I hope this was helpfull.